# Android Push Notification not being received

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am following the tutorial of GCM given [here on AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/). Everything is same except I am using my own Sony Xperia L instead of any emulator. I am able to register my device on my database. However, Google's API console is not showing any change after registration. Here is the screen I am getting before and after registration.[image: API Screen]

I am immediately getting a blank notification (with no data or text) on my cell just after registration. But whenever I try type and send a notification from the web interface built during the tutorial, the page gets refreshed without showing any error, but no notification arrives on my cell.

Please help me solve this problem. I want to manage push notifications based on users in my MySQL database. If any similar descriptive tutorial explains the same, it will be very much helpful to me.
Thanks :)

Comment: whether you are receiving notification in device?

Comment: I am receiving just a single blank notification the moment I register (or maybe, when the registration code is executed) on my app. Also, I am not using localhost, but a free web hosting server supporting PHP and MySQL. I do not receive any further notifications which I try to send from the web Interface built.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem in the beginning but then it was solved. Make sure that your computer from which u are sending the notification and the device are connected to the same wifi.
Also if u r using WAMP, make sure that 'PHP Curl' is enabled.

Comment: Well it worked for me... try  to connect your computer from which u are sending the notification and the device to the same wifi.

Comment: I am assuming u changed the url in CommonUtilities.java under static final String SERVER_URL and also put your Google project id

Comment: Yes, I changed the url to `register.php` file on my server. Just for confirmation, am I supposed to use API key as `Key for browser apps (with referers)` or `Key for server apps (with IP locking)` I tried both, but both giving same problem. I am also not sure that whether the device is getting registered on GCM or not. I can only verify that it's entry gets added on my SQL database on registration..

Comment: U use Browser API Key from the Google APIs Console... y not give it a try using WAMP server and I will try and figure it out and get back to u asap!

Comment: It worked finally! I guess the problem was in the web interface itself! I wrote my php script to send notifications manually and it worked! Thanks a lot for your help! :D

Answer (score 0):

I used my own php script to contact GCM server Instead of the interface `index.php` given in tutorial.

```
<?php    
    include_once './GCM.php';

    $gcm = new GCM();

    $registatoin_ids = array("my_reg_id_here");
    $message= "Wow! a noti!";
    $message = array("price" => $message);

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

    echo $result;
?>
```